# Vue PulseLoader given unexpected token with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I installed the vue-spinner with npm install vue-spinner --save-dev,

and I am trying to use the spinner on my file, but when I use the import

```
import PulseLoader from 'vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue'
```

I get this error:

```
node_modules/vue-spinner/src/PulseLoader.vue:1
<template>
^
```

My gulpfile is requiring vueify, here is it:

```
var elixir = require('laravel-elixir');


require('laravel-elixir-vueify');


elixir(function(mix) {
mix.sass('app.scss','public/assets/css/')
    .browserify('Main.js');

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually don't need to require `laravel-elixir-vueify` in your `guilpfile`, it's easier just to install the original `vueify` (version 9 for Vue 2.0):

```
npm install vueify --save-dev
```

Then add the following to your `package.json`:

```
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "vueify"
    ]
  }
```

Now `elixir` will use the `vueify` transform automatically when `browserify` is called.

**EDIT**
I just took a look at the vue-spinner page and it says that when using `browserify` you need to do the following:

```
import { PulseLoader } from 'vue-spinner/dist/vue-spinner.min.js'
```

So that may fix your problem without the `vueify` step, however, I still recommend avoiding the elixir add ons for the time being because their versioning is all over the place at the moment with `Elixir 6` about to be released and `Vue 2` being newly implemented in `laravel`.

Comment: Thanks for your help and the adivice!